# Selenium grid for different users (with Behat and Mink)

Tags: selenium-grid, behat

Suppose this test logic in a chat system:

- user1 is in home page using browser1 in vm1
- user1 wait until see "myText" in browser1 in vm1
- user2 write "myText" using browser2 in vm2
  (so user1 can proced)

Essentially is a sessions distribution inside a Selenium grid.
How to do this?

Comment: If you need different sessions in the same test then use multiple sessions from Mink http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/managing-sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Behat\Mink\Mink` provides you a way to create, update, delete sessions on your own.
Suppose you have a bdd scenario:

```
Scenario: Users can receive messages sent from their friends
 Given "User 1" user sends "Hello" message to "User 2" user
  Then "User 2" receives "Hello" message from "User 1" user
```

Suppose you have the next methods inside your `ChatContext` file

```
/**
 * @Given /^:sender user sends :message message to :receiver user$/
 */
public function userSendsAMessageToUser($sender, $message, $receiver) {
    $this->initialiseSessions();

    /* Now you need to set default session as firstSession and open browser and send message*/
    $this->getMink()->setDefaultSessionName('firstSession');

    $this->visit('your site');
}

protected function initialiseSessions() {
    /* Initialise your driver with all the required attributes*/
    $driver = new Selenium2Driver();
    $this->firstSession = new Session($driver);

    $driver = new Selenium2Driver();
    $this->secondSession = new Session($driver);

    $this->getMink()->registerSession('firstSession', $this->firstSession);
    $this->getMink()->registerSession('secondSession', $this->secondSession);

}
```

Then you need to implement checking message method and for this you need to switch the session `$this->getMink()->setDefaultSessionName('secondSession');`

Comment: So selenium grid redirect different sessions to different vm?

Comment: So you have Selenium nodes which are connected to selenium grid (They can be connected from any place you want). Lets say you have 2 nodes which serve chrome browsers. Then in your test you call `visit` method with needed url. Grid gets the request, redirects it to the first node and node creates new browser session with your url. Then you make `visit` with another session and another url - grid redirects you to the secod node with new browser session. So you have 2 browser windows independent from each other.